# Determining polynomial values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The polynomial has been edited to include the "x" term

$R(x)= x^4+Ax^3+Bx^2+10x-1$ has a remainder of $-15$ when divided by $x+1$ and a remainder of $39$ when divided by $x-2$. Determine $A$ and $B$.

Comment: There is insufficient information at this time.

Comment: Currently, all we can deduce is that $B-A = -5$. Are you sure there wasn't anything else given in the problem statement?

Comment: $$R(x)=x^4+Ax^3+Bx^2+10x-1=(x+1)q(x)-15$$ if you put x=-1 into it ,$$r(-1)=1-A+B-10-1=0q(-1)-15\\B-A=-5$$ this is one equation and two variable ,so it has many solution .

Answer (score 0):

Hint that makes it straightforward:
For x=-1 the value is -15 and for x=2 the value is 39.
Solve the set of two equation for A and B.